# Finish sth in a finite times/ within a finite time?

Tags: sentence-construction

I am trying to write a sentence to say

```
I want to finish something in a finite time
```

However, I feel uncomfortable with this sentence. I feel

```
I want to finish something within a finite times
```

is better... but I can decide.

Some help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to finish by a particular **time**, you would use the singular

> I want to finish *something* within a finite time.
>   *I want to finish my dissertation within a finite time*

Often the phrase

> set amount of time

may be used instead

> I would like to finish my dissertation within a *set amount of time*.
>   You will have a *set amount of time* to finish the exam.

Both phrases mean there is an endpoint or deadline for completing the task.